# Why does the char pointer not get updated to NULL

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pass-by-value

'''

```
void calling (char *str)
{

    str = NULL;
    
}

int main()
{
    char str2[20];
    calling(str2);

    if(str2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("null");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

'''

Just wondering why did the printf not run.Can I not change the char-array pointer to NULL once its declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you have an array

```
char str2[20];
```

that is `str2` is not a pointer it is an array. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. You can not assign one array to another array like for example

```
char str1[20];
char str2[20];

str1 = str2;
```

In this function call

```
calling(str2);
```

the array designator `str2` is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array and represents an rvalue. You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
calling(str2);

//...

void calling ( /*char *str*/)
{
    char *str = str2;
    str = NULL;

}
```

As you can see the function deals with a copy of the value of an expression that yields the value of the address of the first element of the array `str2`.

Within the function it is the local variable (pointer) `str` that is changed. The original array `str2` declared in main stays unchanged.

Even if you will pass the array by reference you will be unable to change it. For example this program will not compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calling (char ( *str )[20] )
{

    *str = NULL;
    
}

int main()
{
    char str2[20];
    calling( &str2 );

    if(str2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("null");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

because in this statement

```
    *str = NULL;
```

you are trying to assign a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the char pointer not get updated to NULL

Incorrect conclusion.  Inside `calling(char *str)`, the pointer `str` did get updated to `NULL`.

---

> Just wondering why did the printf not run.

Because `&str2[0]` is not `NULL`.
`str2` is an *array*, not a pointer.  With `str2 == NULL`, `str2` is converted to the type and value of the address of the first array element.  The address of the first array element (`&str2[0]`) is not `NULL`.

```
char str2[20];
...
if(str2 == NULL)
{
    printf("null");
}
```

---

> Can I not change the char-array pointer to NULL once its declared.

"char-array pointer" is unclear.

*Array* `str2` in `char str2[20];` cannot change to `NULL`.  An array's address never changes.

*Pointer* `str` in `char *str ... str = NULL;` can get assigned to `NULL`.

---

`calling(str2);` converts array `str2` to the type and value of the address of the first array element, just as if is was `calling(&str2[0]);` and passes that *pointer* to `calling()`.

`void calling(char *str)` receives a *copy* of that pointer.  As `calling()` changes that pointer copy `str` within itself, it does not affect the address of the calling code's `str2`.

---

Remember: an array is not a pointer.  A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in the code:

```
char* calling (char *str)
{
    str = NULL;
    return str;
}
```

You change the local copy of `str` which is not visible to the caller.
You could just have a plain `return NULL;` have the same effect.

```
int main()
{
    char str2[20];
    calling(str2);
```

As mentioned above, the parameter to the function is not affected outside of the function.
You also do not do anything with the return value. The `NULL` value is just discarded.
Also there is no pointer existing in `main` at all that could be updaed.

You have an array. Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays.
You can never assign a value to the array variable as it represents the location in memory where the array members are stored.

As mentioned in comments you should get hands on y good book to learn C.
Especially chapters about arrays, pointers and passing data into and out of functions should be relevant for you.

Comment: So.. I know that when you pass an array in c , the whole array is not copied but instead the array kind of decomposes to a pointer.Since it is more like passing by pointer/reference we are able to change the values of the array in the  function call.( it won't be a local copy?) What I was wondering is how does C enforce the difference between an array decomposed pointer vs lets say an integer pointer if i try to update the address which the pointer is pointing to inside the function call..!

Comment: You are right about passing arrays. Instead of all elements only a pointer to first element is passed. That is called "the array decays to a pointer". As a result we can indeed modify the values in that array. If it was a pointer that you passed into a function, it would also be a local copy. But you cannot modify that pointer in either case. It only affects the pointer inside the called function.

Comment: This means if you want to update the pointer itself, you must pass the pointer by reference, i.e. use `int **param`. Then you can update `*param=new_addr;`. As an array is no pointer, you cannot pass an array into a function that expects the address of a pointer.